# Why is my SQL FOREIGN KEY clause returning an error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in SQL just started learning yesterday so I can start making back - end applications. This is the code I am using, this doesn't work and returns and error in mySQL

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    employ_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    birthday DATE,
    gender VARCHAR(1),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
);


CREATE TABLE branch (
    branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    branch_name VARCHAR(40),
    mgr_id INT 
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES employee(employ_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    mgr_start_date DATE
);
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the the exact text of the error message you're seeing (not a screenshot, please) to the question, rather than a vague statement that "this doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE branch (
branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
branch_name VARCHAR(40),
mgr_start_date DATE,
mgr_id int,
CONSTRAINT FK_mrg_id FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(employ_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Could you please tell me what did you change?